# how to debug openshift origin from source code?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Is there a step-by-step guide how to debug openshift origin from source code ?

I googled a lot but with no luck.

Comment: What are you trying to debug? Explain what the problem is and then can possibly guide you better.

Comment: I'm trying to make some code changes on openshift origin.  For example: I'd like to add some of my own new feature ..

Comment: You would be better off joining the dev list at http://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo and discuss what you want to do with the core developers. They can then provide guidance.